# How do I switch which is already in a fragment to move from one fragment to another (Java) in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have linked a switch to shift from Fragment1 to Fragment2 but I do not know how to return to Fragment1 if the switch is clicked again.

Answer (score 1):

Do not put the switch inside fragment. You should include the switch in parent layout and change the fragment when switch is clicked.

For eg;

You include switch in linear layout below that layout you have framelayout in which you are committing the fragments.

Comment: This should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution: use `switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener` and `transaction.replace`. For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fTrans.add(R.id.your_fragment_container, frag1);

    Switch switch = findViewById(R.id.switch);
    if (switch != null) {
        switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }
    frag1 = new Fragment1();
    frag2 = new Fragment2();
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if(isChecked){
            fTrans.replace(R.id.your_fragment_container, frag2);
        }else{
            fTrans.replace(R.id.your_fragment_container, frag1);
        }
}
```

}

`R.id.your_fragment_container` is a layout for your two fragments

Comment: Can we implement the same code in inside a fragment class ? Because setContentView seems to not work

Comment: for fragments use:
    `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` and inside it: `inflater.inflate(R.layout.ads_tab, container, false)`